# How can i make in a multiplayer sprite kit game all the devices have same map?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-center

I'm having an iOS Sprit Kit multiplayer game via Game Center and I'm trying to have same generated map on both devices. How can i manage that?

- Generating and sending will make both devices have the other device map
- Live generating  it's sending an NSData to other device each 0.5 - 2 seconds
- I've tried rand() and srand(). Didn't quite managed the desired result (Maybe i was wrong with something).

Comment: How are you sending the data? You could use [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html) and set up one device as a central, and have the other devices as peripherals. Then the central could make all the decisions i.e. provide all the maps e.t.c and the peripherals could just respond.

Comment: it's via GameCenter..I cannot use Bluetooth..

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard code to do that. You would need to setup a third party server to download content.

You can however include a number of different maps as part of your app and select a random map as part of a new game. Including the maps in your code enables all users to instantly have access to it without the need for additional downloads.